# What am I doing wrong with my render method that I'm receiving "Invariant Violation" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I'm starting a new React Native project, I used 'expo init' and chose a blank managed project as my template. I have a couple screens and components from a different project, that I'd like to copy over into my new one. I'm receiving the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `CreateAccountForm`.

I can't figure out what's going on. I'm pretty sure I have everything setup exactly as I did in my first project which renders everything fine. I'm using React Navigation and my new project renders the "HomeScreen" fine as the "initialRouteName". However, whenever I try to set the initial route to 'CreateNewAccountScreen' I receive the error above.

I've tested it, and the 'CreateNewAccountScreen' will render propery as my initial route, as long as it's not trying to render the 'CreateAccountForm' component nested inside of it. Upon replacing the `<CreateAccountForm>` component with a simple `<Text>Hi!<Text>`, it rendered the screen fine with no problem, along with the `<Advertisement>` component.

**HomeScreeen:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import Advertisement from '../components/Advertisement';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.logo}
        source={require('../assets/TPLookupLogo.png')} 
        style={{height: 200, width: 350, marginBottom: 40}} 
        resizeMode="contain">
        </Image>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.btnsContainer}>
        <Button 
        style={styles.button}
        appearance="outline"
        onPress={()=>{console.log('To New User')}}
        title='New User'
        />
        <Button 
        style={styles.button} 
        appearance="outline"
        onPress={()=>{console.log('To Login')}}
        title='Login'
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.adContainer}>
        <Advertisement/>
      </View>
    </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logoContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  btnsContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    width: '40%',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
  },
  button: {
    marginVertical: 4,
    },
  adContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
})

export default HomeScreen;
```

**AppNavigator:**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import CreateNewAccountScreen from '../screens/CreateNewAccountScreen';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    CreateNewAccount: CreateNewAccountScreen

    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'CreateNewAccount'
    }
  )

  export default AppNavigator;
```

**CreateNewAccountScreen:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import CreateAccountForm from '../components/CreateAccountForm';
import Advertisement from '../components/Advertisement';

const CreateNewAccountScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
         <View style={styles.formContainer}>
           <CreateAccountForm/>
         </View>
         <View style={styles.adContainer}>
           <Advertisement/>
         </View> 
       </View>     
     );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer:{
      flex: 1,
    },
    formContainer: {
      flex: 8,
    },
    adContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    }
  })

CreateNewAccountScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Create Account'
}

export default CreateNewAccountScreen;
```

**CreateAccountForm:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Input, Button } from 'react-native';

const CreateAccountForm = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [company, setCompany] = useState('');
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [city, setCity] = useState('');
    const [stateName, setStateName] = useState('');
    const [zip, setZip] = useState('');

    const onChangeEmailHandler = value => {
        setEmail(value);
    }

    const onChangePasswordHandler = value => {
        setPassword(value);
    }

    const onChangeCompanyHandler = value => {
        setCompany(value);
    }

    const onChangeFirstNameHandler = value => {
        setFirstName(value);
    }

    const onChangeLastNameHandler = value => {
        setLastName(value);
    }

    const onChangeAddressHandler = value => {
       setAddress(value);
    }

    const onChangeCityHandler = value => {
        setCity(value);
    }

    const onChangeStateNameHandler = value => {
        setStateName(value)
    }

    const onChangeZipHandler = value => {
        setZip(value);
    }

    const RegisterUserHandler = props => {
        let emailLength = email.length;
        let passwordLength = password.length;
        if (emailLength === 0 || passwordLength === 0)
        {
            console.log('Email & Password cannot be blank.');
        }
        else
        {
            registerUser()
        }
    }

    async function registerUser () {
        let headers = {
            'X-Authorization': "",
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            };
        let body = JSON.stringify({
            Email: email,
            Password: password,
            Company: company,
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            Address: address,
            City: city,
            State: stateName,
            Zipcode: zip
        })
        let response = await fetch('', 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: body
        });
        let responseJson = await response.json()
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Input
                style={styles.input}
                type="text"
                value={email}
                placeholder="Email"
                onChangeText={onChangeEmailHandler}
                />
                <Input
                style={styles.input}
                type="text"
                value={password}
                placeholder="Password"
                onChangeText={onChangePasswordHandler}
                />
                <Input
                style={styles.input}
                type="text"
                value={company}
                placeholder="Company"
                onChangeText={onChangeCompanyHandler}
                />
                <Input
                style={styles.input}
                value={firstName}
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChangeText={onChangeFirstNameHandler}
                />
                <Input
                style={styles.input}
                value={lastName}
                placeholder="Last Name"
                onChangeText={onChangeLastNameHandler}
                />
                <Input
                style={styles.input}
                value={address}
                placeholder="Address"
                onChangeText={onChangeAddressHandler}
                />
                <View style={styles.rowInputsContainer}>
                    <Input 
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={city}
                    style={styles.rowInput}
                    placeholder="City"
                    onChangeText={onChangeCityHandler}
                    />
                    <Input
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={stateName}
                    style={{...styles.rowInput, ...styles.centerRowInput}}
                    placeholder="State"
                    onChangeText={onChangeStateNameHandler}
                    />
                    <Input
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={zip}
                    style={styles.rowInput}
                    placeholder="Zip"
                    onChangeText={onChangeZipHandler}
                    />
                </View>
                <Button 
                style={styles.btn}
                onPress={RegisterUserHandler}
                title='Register'
                />
        </View>
    )   
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      width: '75%',
      alignSelf: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    rowInputsContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 16
    },
    rowInput: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    centerRowInput: {
        marginHorizontal: 4
    },
    input: {
        marginVertical: 8
    }
})

export default CreateAccountForm;
```

This exact same setup renders everything fine with no problem in my first application. So I don't understand where I went wrong. Any help, greatly appreciated, thanks, peace!

Comment: Please reduce the code snippet to only the necessary to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Also, how do you import `CreateAccountForm`?

Comment: @devserkan at the top of CreateNewAccountScreen I have:

import CreateAccountForm from '../components/CreateAccountForm';

Comment: Does it work if `CreateAccountForm` renders(returns) just a piece of text?

Comment: @devserkan Yes it does! if I just put a `<Text>Hello from CreateAccountForm</Text>` it renders fine! It's when I added all the other stuff inside of the `<View style={styles.mainContainer}>`...which worked fine in my first project?.

Comment: I wasn't the one asked that but this was a good question :) So, try to add one by one and find what causes this. I couldn't see anything in the current code but there is too much :)

Comment: Ah, but it is an object? Forget about that question, you are using it in `style`.

Comment: @devserkan sorry, you've lost me, what do you mean by 'but it is an object?' Forget about what question? and what does it matter that I'm using it in style?

Comment: Forget about my last comment please :) I just saw it as you are using `styles.mainContainer` in your view directly but actually you are passing it to your element's `style`. This is what I meant and no problem with that. Try to add pieces one by one or as a block if you can't see where is the problem directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native has `TextInput` component and not `Input` component. Can you please check while importing it in **CreateAccountForm**.